# Salt-Api doen't include unsuccessful queries

Tags: salt-stack

I have installed salt 2016.3.2 on several machines and also configured salt-api to send commands using REST calls. It works fine but I have a minor problem.

When I call a function from an execution module (say `test.ping`) I can see disconnected minions ids in the CLI output but the same command using salt-api doesn't include failed minions ids.

For example:

```
salt '*' test.ping
linux1:
    True
win1:
    Minion did not return. [Not connected]

curl -b cookies.in -sSk http://localhost:8000 -H 'Accept: application/json' -d client=local -d tgt='*' -d fun='test.ping'
{"return" : [{"linux1" : true}]}
```

How can I see all nodes regardless of success or failure in the REST result? (including "win1" in the above example)

Thanks.

Comment: I could be wrong, but at a first glance this issue looks similar to this: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/20240#issuecomment-87709212 - no progress since 2015

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't find anything useful in that issue.